# How do I apply a patch that contains a file that doesn't exist?

Tags: svn, patch

I'm applying a patch to an svn working copy. In the patch file contains a new file.

Patch would normally return something like this:

```
can't find file to patch at input line 344
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/user-features/src/main/java/com/app2/util/SearchRelevanceHelper.java b/user-features/src/main/java/com/app2/util/SearchRelevanceHelper.java
|new file mode 100644
|index 0000000..c10b3ae
|--- /dev/null
|+++ b/user-features/src/main/java/com/yookos/util/SearchRelevanceHelper.java
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

How do I handle this?

Comment: Your patch file was generated by `Git`. `git help diff` says "*What the -p option produces is slightly different from the traditional diff format*". Maybe that is the reason `patch` cannot apply it...

Comment: The patch file was created using `git format-patch`

Comment: Excerpt from: [`man help format-patch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch#_discussion): "*The patch produced by `git format-patch` is in UNIX mailbox format...* ... *...and apply them with `git am`*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your patch with the cygwin patch command.

```
afusilde@LFR408288 ~/testdir
$ cat newpatch
diff --git a/user-features/src/main/java/com/app2/util/SearchRelevanceHelper.java b/user-features/src/main/java/com/app2/util/SearchRelevanceHelper.java
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..c10b3ae
--- /dev/null
+++ b/user-features/src/main/java/com/yookos/util/SearchRelevanceHelper.java

afusilde@LFR408288 ~/testdir
$ mkdir test

afusilde@LFR408288 ~/testdir
$ cd test

afusilde@LFR408288 ~/testdir/test
$ patch < ../newpatch
patching file SearchRelevanceHelper.java

afusilde@LFR408288 ~/testdir/test
$ ls
SearchRelevanceHelper.java
```

No problem for me. Do you use a **GNU patch** command ?